# NSString lacks basic method in plugin for securityAgent

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, runtime

I'm working on plugin project for securityAgent, and it looks like NSString object lacks some basic integer conversion methods in this particular environment.

for example :

```
[myString longLongValue]
```

would yield an exception with the following log message:

```
-[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8035abf638a27af
```

However, other related methods are working just fine like `UTF8String`.

Any idea if it's related to the fact that this project is a plugin running under `securityAgentHelper` ? any other ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: `longLongValue` is interface of `NSString`, but `unsignedIntValue` of `NSValue`. So show code of usage, because it seems the origin of the issue is different.

Comment: What is the source of this NSString? Are you obtaining it by parsing something?